# Как удалить тег <h2> в functions.php на wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

нужно удалить кусок кода при помощи php вот код `<h2 class="widgettitle">Корзина</h2>`.
Или просто убрать тег `<h2>` что бы получилось так `<div class="widgettitle">Корзина</div>`
Сайт на котором нужно это сделать https://loftbuy.com.ua/
P.s Пробовал так не работает

```
$string = '<h2 class="widgettitle">Корзина</h2>';
$string = preg_replace("/<h2\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/h2>/is", "<div>$2</div>", $string);
echo($string);
```

Comment: $string = '<h2 class="widgettitle">Корзина</h2>';
$string=str_replace('<h2', '<div', $string);
$string=str_replace('</h2>', '</div>', $string);

Comment: К сожалению код не работает

Answer (score 1):

Если текст внутри тегов всегда один и тот же, то можно просто через `str_replace`:

```
$html   = 'Тут весь ваш контент';
$from   = '<h2 class="widgettitle">Корзина</h2>';
$to     = '<div class="widgettitle">Корзина</div>';
$result = str_replace( $from, $to, $html );

echo $result;
```